# how to disable a button

Tags: javascript

I've been searching in how to disable input type=button. I have this code here:

```
<input type="button" value="&nbsp;Send&nbsp;" id="submit" name="submit" data-inline="true" data-icon="edit">
```

How to disable this in JavaScript? I'm also planning it when I clicked checkbox the button will be enabled.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it like this:

```
$('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
```

And enable it again with a checkbox like this:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#submit').attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);
```

Read about [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)